# php json_decode returns null even for utf-8 string with no spaces or other special characters

Tags: php, json

My json_decode returns null and I think I have tried everything before making this post.  Please advise me.

I use Windows Live REST API to read user albums and then photos. json_decode works great to decode the response from all other Windows live end points but not from this one :(...

```
    $albums_url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/".$albumId."/photos?access_token=" . urlencode($accessToken);

    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
    $ch = curl_init($albums_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "my web site domain name here");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
    $albumPhotosResponse=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

When json response arrives it contains lots of \r and \n in it. Even between lines. So I get clean all of it out.

1.I trim it

`$albumPhotosResponse = trim($albumPhotosResponse);`

2.Remove all `\n` and `\r`

`$albumPhotosResponse = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"),"",$albumPhotosResponse);`

3.And just to make sure there are no extra spaces I do this

`$albumPhotosResponse = preg_replace('!\s+!', '', $albumPhotosResponse);`

I googled around and have found that for many developers the issue was with `json` value being not `UTF-8` encoded. So I have tried this as well.

`$photoAlbumsResponse = json_decode(utf8_encode($photoAlbumsResponse),true);`

Chrome does display and format received json document properly. This tells me there are no problems with the structure of json document. I can fold and unfold json objects using visual tools. json is correct. But when I try to `json_decode()` it. It returns null :(

Please advise me how to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Here is JSON document itself:

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "file.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!126",
      "from": {
        "name": "SergeyKargopolov",
        "id": "f6099d461e678395"
      },
      "name": "IMG_5398_small.jpg",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": "folder.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!125",
      "size": 84683,
      "comments_count": 0,
      "comments_enabled": true,
      "tags_count": 0,
      "tags_enabled": true,
      "picture": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mkGF4H0SO63lkIzy-uMOV5AES5ndgqynGmJwWGUOfkmdVsEU80dW2UnbDcF3_EoYpV8oFH6UB_AxnDZ8hmOud_AvdU65BSPJvE8yYfACcWYZyab2cqRo_gk2S851c89Fb/IMG_5398_small.jpg?psid=1",
      "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mcTvD8EbPp9R2oBWP446Jp40SZmDrNQ5Cc1ssIIwTN5f9btKk3NnykeK10-CXBakQ0D4jRz9ugXpJSVerTdZ4JfA9UOkemKB75IDO9pkL4IrvtiDpyTj5dzf4kAGolzkc/IMG_5398_small.jpg?psid=1",
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 800,
          "width": 533,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m-fnaGh1zrR0sLanBP0D_wzT4ocJTqKE2A_8rb8n6_U_FlMt8Rp_dhoEuDBE4f1nkG3ApxWndOsrPfxB-phxJ7-4O343mS5I5n67zE2ZbfI2F_a-SJFhlL7_QcXsobhvU/IMG_5398_small.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "normal"
        },
        {
          "height": 176,
          "width": 117,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2my2M-gI6cZv33A0ueydYDxackIY4w7vqhmxksbZuBddvZXHsPykgivJTio_VlnSP0hOXu8eKRwRXRfnGK6Flk6HLhsFE4XlJjPyhc9pQ9IdSGV3F7JYZQKxZ7Pcp3Y3Cb/IMG_5398_small.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "album"
        },
        {
          "height": 96,
          "width": 63,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mkGF4H0SO63lkIzy-uMOV5AES5ndgqynGmJwWGUOfkmdVsEU80dW2UnbDcF3_EoYpV8oFH6UB_AxnDZ8hmOud_AvdU65BSPJvE8yYfACcWYZyab2cqRo_gk2S851c89Fb/IMG_5398_small.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "thumbnail"
        },
        {
          "height": 900,
          "width": 600,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mcTvD8EbPp9R2oBWP446Jp40SZmDrNQ5Cc1ssIIwTN5f9btKk3NnykeK10-CXBakQ0D4jRz9ugXpJSVerTdZ4JfA9UOkemKB75IDO9pkL4IrvtiDpyTj5dzf4kAGolzkc/IMG_5398_small.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "full"
        }
      ],
      "link": "https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=f6099d461e678395&page=view&resid=F6099D461E678395!126&parid=F6099D461E678395!125",
      "when_taken": null,
      "height": 900,
      "width": 600,
      "type": "photo",
      "camera_make": null,
      "camera_model": null,
      "focal_ratio": 0,
      "focal_length": 0,
      "exposure_numerator": 0,
      "exposure_denominator": 0,
      "created_time": "2010-07-27T04:19:59+0000",
      "updated_time": "2010-07-27T04:20:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "file.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!131",
      "from": {
        "name": "SergeyKargopolov",
        "id": "f6099d461e678395"
      },
      "name": "011s769f.jpg",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": "folder.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!125",
      "size": 96091,
      "comments_count": 0,
      "comments_enabled": true,
      "tags_count": 0,
      "tags_enabled": true,
      "picture": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m5gYxO0yiumEjjK29fEI7AaLP8kCKmHVSU5UI7XWb-l2z0uZRfCyHBVujSkAQhjjeZHww1sqfLlsg5nY4jUpfkgcTibKw7xc5Qfi3zcHkB22BmG-gMyZi8xDjM0XXWOdA/011s769f.jpg?psid=1",
      "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mZicAQqNBndn2-DlU0uAh1yK5AgoB2G2zqBnVr2nXVlDgs9nxk441RPuHa8sqUHeCk4cRK6lhfPDi9fcbVRVBlapQ9w_xSh4I86E0v9hE1368sIPGrHEH4pNFqs4CA7Y-/011s769f.jpg?psid=1",
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 800,
          "width": 529,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mNp-KCqcEvWN0lYYO129mMIw8AmcCccv9rG8RawrQort6wNapXghZVlxHKLngDwJxo4P-3gdzHSPxlfpKVFgdvQJY_sVC-o3El9k9nkNFpop162qGlEAvooNvlqIAlaPH/011s769f.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "normal"
        },
        {
          "height": 176,
          "width": 116,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mJKrnTHXH6yWv4Eb9lMpqDBED7QSVaoc6Fs1PHPtiqijK8iw7A0l2e9gOMvRvG0esCVWQbG3dtUVS1r0nXjabjG1xikqc586nf2GBeNMmSZYRDWa143yRLUkU5uldZ7ko/011s769f.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "album"
        },
        {
          "height": 96,
          "width": 63,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m5gYxO0yiumEjjK29fEI7AaLP8kCKmHVSU5UI7XWb-l2z0uZRfCyHBVujSkAQhjjeZHww1sqfLlsg5nY4jUpfkgcTibKw7xc5Qfi3zcHkB22BmG-gMyZi8xDjM0XXWOdA/011s769f.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "thumbnail"
        },
        {
          "height": 1024,
          "width": 678,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mZicAQqNBndn2-DlU0uAh1yK5AgoB2G2zqBnVr2nXVlDgs9nxk441RPuHa8sqUHeCk4cRK6lhfPDi9fcbVRVBlapQ9w_xSh4I86E0v9hE1368sIPGrHEH4pNFqs4CA7Y-/011s769f.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "full"
        }
      ],
      "link": "https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=f6099d461e678395&page=view&resid=F6099D461E678395!131&parid=F6099D461E678395!125",
      "when_taken": "2010-10-30T12:08:10+0000",
      "height": 1024,
      "width": 678,
      "type": "photo",
      "camera_make": null,
      "camera_model": null,
      "focal_ratio": 0,
      "focal_length": 0,
      "exposure_numerator": 0,
      "exposure_denominator": 0,
      "created_time": "2010-11-10T21:34:19+0000",
      "updated_time": "2010-11-12T21:27:17+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "file.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!132",
      "from": {
        "name": "SergeyKargopolov",
        "id": "f6099d461e678395"
      },
      "name": "0111facs.jpg",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": "folder.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!125",
      "size": 103077,
      "comments_count": 0,
      "comments_enabled": true,
      "tags_count": 0,
      "tags_enabled": true,
      "picture": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m6gsOPgubuCzBpTvBOfyuYUiY33ToLDcl1J7IFPTkSBCdtd7AxIgdTr22k0LXoqhwzL3d7ZPESa3umbHHp37gNCEyoygH8WXnxOnNWW1xt_huFbcu1Au8kl5eF_bhvM-I/0111facs.jpg?psid=1",
      "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m3qQ0ew5NYVPazHoNNYlSdZszzzJCIVmH-6pSBwAAhmsruUq6BmciwF2Hnxv7h7fv2jdjPqPWKjs6AQ-_NuQrW2CnFMJ27k6A_DULXRwhr1K-fZr2LN0xLiIAocHL9gtk/0111facs.jpg?psid=1",
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 540,
          "width": 800,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mfTbhvgI9mawwJUXWqzPWFLUDfwmBECiF7OYMXV5etprNG7gre5i7FQSQTZ3r8Oe9MfsmUKK40-EQLTOUlUHGuRz4Es1b_stSXuHIYDwJYeJ-AvcDe4SLFhx5G7lYacV1/0111facs.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "normal"
        },
        {
          "height": 118,
          "width": 176,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m0vrDF8_R1FoZcEmgwBpkWcPWu902jJLlKzGOv4R4UIQvMHbSHNbLLAyUrKJagbHypqxZeUaQpwJXayLUxCExKEzsWBF0pD0_pWNDfk9NmfDlB_dtU3y0PlNIIATuSoTC/0111facs.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "album"
        },
        {
          "height": 64,
          "width": 96,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m6gsOPgubuCzBpTvBOfyuYUiY33ToLDcl1J7IFPTkSBCdtd7AxIgdTr22k0LXoqhwzL3d7ZPESa3umbHHp37gNCEyoygH8WXnxOnNWW1xt_huFbcu1Au8kl5eF_bhvM-I/0111facs.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "thumbnail"
        },
        {
          "height": 608,
          "width": 900,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m3qQ0ew5NYVPazHoNNYlSdZszzzJCIVmH-6pSBwAAhmsruUq6BmciwF2Hnxv7h7fv2jdjPqPWKjs6AQ-_NuQrW2CnFMJ27k6A_DULXRwhr1K-fZr2LN0xLiIAocHL9gtk/0111facs.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "full"
        }
      ],
      "link": "https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=f6099d461e678395&page=view&resid=F6099D461E678395!132&parid=F6099D461E678395!125",
      "when_taken": null,
      "height": 608,
      "width": 900,
      "type": "photo",
      "camera_make": null,
      "camera_model": null,
      "focal_ratio": 0,
      "focal_length": 0,
      "exposure_numerator": 0,
      "exposure_denominator": 0,
      "created_time": "2010-11-10T21:34:21+0000",
      "updated_time": "2010-11-10T21:34:21+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "file.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!133",
      "from": {
        "name": "SergeyKargopolov",
        "id": "f6099d461e678395"
      },
      "name": "0111tcez.jpg",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": "folder.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!125",
      "size": 92916,
      "comments_count": 0,
      "comments_enabled": true,
      "tags_count": 0,
      "tags_enabled": true,
      "picture": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m1cj77LH9hzorTOA0jZ16Np2J5-Ut9_9VwZKQ-Er9lXfDcgc6iF1gfQzVEzgLIEqd5Q_gxKAdyJFil3JB9G7ku6eMJZCplG6dz1UQcU4IkwIrI_U8f8y04Hyy_Dj2oTy2/0111tcez.jpg?psid=1",
      "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mqv57qXM8TmrOqmJVkPohDxtApxRsWRIuzQYDd2JT_8KbO5bv72yUE_UVX-Z5-xA0eSYXqz2x42s314MOq8xc7lyi7cuaFNgEV1KupIfJ8R0K5xF1xRwdVxL4b010c8r-/0111tcez.jpg?psid=1",
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 800,
          "width": 554,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mdRIJj3A6tNLVr6cXwGRJZeDDbkI78YEujBv_i5UmBCoLYnqBm2Iv06W_KlZIXNeBKby3Z1y_Oeb2tVUTmt4gBA/0111tcez.jpg?psid=1&ck=16&ex=720",
          "type": "normal"
        },
        {
          "height": 176,
          "width": 121,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mjb6q9PCcQuUEG8qDNw8wri6Slsj5SjiQz7qJuk235sNX7a0z0WcW25X2Q11dcSrJsssTWtDYZgq6hKFlon3SDxKELEnThqN0Xq5y6Ia7XgPHiTiLQngjRaXiKCpHfhQu/0111tcez.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "album"
        },
        {
          "height": 96,
          "width": 66,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2m1cj77LH9hzorTOA0jZ16Np2J5-Ut9_9VwZKQ-Er9lXfDcgc6iF1gfQzVEzgLIEqd5Q_gxKAdyJFil3JB9G7ku6eMJZCplG6dz1UQcU4IkwIrI_U8f8y04Hyy_Dj2oTy2/0111tcez.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "thumbnail"
        },
        {
          "height": 900,
          "width": 624,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mqv57qXM8TmrOqmJVkPohDxtApxRsWRIuzQYDd2JT_8KbO5bv72yUE_UVX-Z5-xA0eSYXqz2x42s314MOq8xc7lyi7cuaFNgEV1KupIfJ8R0K5xF1xRwdVxL4b010c8r-/0111tcez.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "full"
        }
      ],
      "link": "https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=f6099d461e678395&page=view&resid=F6099D461E678395!133&parid=F6099D461E678395!125",
      "when_taken": null,
      "height": 900,
      "width": 624,
      "type": "photo",
      "camera_make": null,
      "camera_model": null,
      "focal_ratio": 0,
      "focal_length": 0,
      "exposure_numerator": 0,
      "exposure_denominator": 0,
      "created_time": "2010-11-10T21:34:21+0000",
      "updated_time": "2010-11-10T21:34:22+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "file.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!142",
      "from": {
        "name": "SergeyKargopolov",
        "id": "f6099d461e678395"
      },
      "name": "011xfx15.jpg",
      "description": "ALLURE/",
      "parent_id": "folder.f6099d461e678395.F6099D461E678395!125",
      "size": 183605,
      "comments_count": 0,
      "comments_enabled": true,
      "tags_count": 0,
      "tags_enabled": true,
      "picture": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mnESJYaEhmj46Iq_sDjjZVgrs8636E_DuHdGHMVEJh558hgoc1KzIwGjckWLRhieCuG_wpq2KZ0EYQxkONF3Pe3ID5eCz2IiVOlrFp4p2U1hC1jQ4-z-DQ3hragV2otEg/011xfx15.jpg?psid=1",
      "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mNGQLRETzgJSL4go-5FJ2rtDayq-rOCcD5CphPiSLoXZNn1t_w3uGr-mVMvuhVdJVIFrBLtvKL-wXFc7Pwk5MMCHJwZsZ0t_xOVXLXKq6eSfjYanu0xnCuvnFwB1H5bwq/011xfx15.jpg?psid=1",
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 496,
          "width": 800,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2muc04ASn8PnEpsbLKR1t85o7ehGUQg5Q5ZMkjvQ14wPqrS-ycSGnSa-ujmrtB9JRSGBx_BlE3E36EfZmRrkQd9g/011xfx15.jpg?psid=1&ck=16&ex=720",
          "type": "normal"
        },
        {
          "height": 108,
          "width": 176,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mnJNZVApUSdeKRGH6TDT4BJ_eNmHeVKhcdZUsjFyaQAXzL-CkAaiSADroRCylRVMf7u7iFv6wse7CPhc6ijZMwSX5eGEZntFzFHPvZyVIpcd1U-nmW8_ckzFIPFmhd2NW/011xfx15.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "album"
        },
        {
          "height": 58,
          "width": 96,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mnESJYaEhmj46Iq_sDjjZVgrs8636E_DuHdGHMVEJh558hgoc1KzIwGjckWLRhieCuG_wpq2KZ0EYQxkONF3Pe3ID5eCz2IiVOlrFp4p2U1hC1jQ4-z-DQ3hragV2otEg/011xfx15.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "thumbnail"
        },
        {
          "height": 682,
          "width": 1100,
          "source": "https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2mNGQLRETzgJSL4go-5FJ2rtDayq-rOCcD5CphPiSLoXZNn1t_w3uGr-mVMvuhVdJVIFrBLtvKL-wXFc7Pwk5MMCHJwZsZ0t_xOVXLXKq6eSfjYanu0xnCuvnFwB1H5bwq/011xfx15.jpg?psid=1",
          "type": "full"
        }
      ],
      "link": "https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=f6099d461e678395&page=view&resid=F6099D461E678395!142&parid=F6099D461E678395!125",
      "when_taken": "2010-11-11T21:07:02+0000",
      "height": 682,
      "width": 1100,
      "type": "photo",
      "camera_make": null,
      "camera_model": null,
      "focal_ratio": 0,
      "focal_length": 0,
      "exposure_numerator": 0,
      "exposure_denominator": 0,
      "created_time": "2010-11-15T21:48:22+0000",
      "updated_time": "2010-11-15T21:48:23+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you show us the JSON which causes your problems? echo it?

Comment: @MightyPork thank you for your comment. I have edited my question to add JSON document I am trying to json_decode.

Comment: I just tried "json_decode()" with your JSON, and it gives no errors and parses the JSON data all right. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @MightyPork that is the problem :(. This JSON works well if copied and paste somewhere else. If I do echo $albumPhotosResponse I can see JSON document well formatted. If I do json_decode($albumPhotosResponse) right away as a next line of my code, I get null.... I trim it, I clear spaces, I convert it into utf-8 nothing helps... If I echo it and copy somewhere else, I see no issues with it.... :( very confusing.

Comment: May be there are other special characters that get cleared when text is transferred via copy&paste? Is there a way to make curl response as json-only meaning no \r, \n or spaces or any other hidden characters...?

Comment: spaces, tabs etc in JSON are not a problem, they are allowed - leave them alone and focus on the other stuff.

Comment: out of ideas where else to look :(. JSON document looks to be perfectly valid but still json_decode does not work... I have contacted Windows live support... May be there problem is somewhere there.

Comment: Can not believe it. Tried it couple of hours later and things just worked!!! Have not changed anything. Simply ran my code again! May be emailing Windows Live API team did help?.. JSON looks exactly the same as it was a few hours ago. Do not see any differences..